# How to access an array of ID using an event trigger with checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help with my problem.
I created a static form. With a lots of  and checkboxes. My problem is, I am integrating a javascript code for the selection of checkboxes. When the user check the parent checkboxes it will automatically check the subcategory. I can do this one by one (hardcoded). But it is a lot of work. What I think is I will put all of the IDs in an array and create a loop or event that will access them. But I don't know how. Ok that's all.

Here's my code: I am using CI and jquery 1.5

```
//here's the array

var checkboxParentMenu = ["checkAllFilipino","checkAllContinental","checkAllAsian","checkAllOthers"];
var checkboxChildMenu = ["filipino_cat","continental_cat","asian_cat","others_cat"];
```

Now here's the manual way.

```
$("input[data-check='checkAllFilipino']").change(function(){
        $("#filipino_cat").find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked",this.checked);
});
```

Here's the pattern sample

```
<div id="parentTab">

    <div id="categoryTab">
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </div>

        <div id="subCategoryTab">
           <input type="checkbox" />
        </div>

           <div id="childOfSubCategory">
               <input type="checkbox" />
           </div>
    ....
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way out is

```
var checkboxParentMenu = ["checkAllFilipino", "checkAllContinental", "checkAllAsian", "checkAllOthers"];
var checkboxChildMenu = ["filipino_cat", "continental_cat", "asian_cat", "others_cat"];

$.each(checkboxParentMenu, function (idx, name) {
    $('input[data-check="' + name + '"]').change(function () {
        $("#" + checkboxChildMenu[idx]).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", this.checked);
    });
})
```

But I would recommend

```
<input type="checkbox" data-check="checkAllFilipino" data-target="#filipino_cat" />CHECK ALL
<br/>
```

then

```
$('input').filter('[data-check="checkAllFilipino"], [data-check="checkAllContinental"], [data-check="checkAllAsian"], [data-check="checkAllOthers"]').change(function () {
    $($(this).data('target')).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9U6pt/)

Comment: Ok sir thanks again. I really appreciate your help for me. I am really a beginner in jquery that's why I am grateful that you helped me with my code.

Comment: One more thing sir. I have a part that has a subcategory. Is it the same process too?

Comment: @RochelleCanale in the second sample there was a bug which I fixed now... check the update

Comment: Because subcategory doesn't not check/uncheck the checkboxes below.

Comment: @RochelleCanale please update the attached fiddle to replicate your case

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39882/discussion-between-rochelle-canale-and-arun-p-johny)

Answer (score 2):

The super easy way out would be to actually nest the divs, then you could do this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parentTab">
    <div id="categoryTab">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <div id="subCategoryTab">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div id="childOfSubCategory">
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will study that code. Because as of now my jquery is outdated version. That's why i can't use prop() function.

Comment: My apologies, I've edited it to work for jQuery 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) in place of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) like,

```
var checkboxParentMenu = ["checkAllFilipino","checkAllContinental","checkAllAsian","checkAllOthers"];
var checkboxChildMenu = ["filipino_cat","continental_cat","asian_cat","others_cat"];

$.each(checkboxParentMenu ,function(i,parentChk){
   $("input[data-check='"+parentChk+'").on(change',function(){
      $('#'+checkboxChildMenu[i]).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked",this.checked);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions sir. It is working also. But prop() function doesn't work with my jquery version.